# jhipster saving files only to home directory

Tags: jhipster

I accidentally ran jhipster in my home directory.
Now when I run jhipster after creating a folder, still the files are being created in the home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove .yo-rc.json from your home directory.